# How to understand the concurrency of requests from client-side by gRPC in the TF-Serving example?

Tags: multithreading, tensorflow, grpc, tensorflow-serving, condition-variable

**Background**

According to [Serving a TensorFlow Model](https://www.tensorflow.org/tfx/serving/serving_basic),

The program in [mnist client](https://github.com/tensorflow/serving/blob/e085cb37b4b5c62154aa063dcbb781b24d5b3fd4/tensorflow_serving/example/mnist_client.py) is about

> A client that talks to tensorflow_model_server loaded with mnist model.
>
> The client downloads test images of mnist data set, queries the service with
>
> such test images to get predictions, and calculates the inference error rate.

**Problem**

I have some difficulties to understand the concurrency of requests from client-side by gRPC.

1. [Define concurrency](https://github.com/tensorflow/serving/blob/master/tensorflow_serving/example/mnist_client.py#L45)
2. [Concurrency related code](https://github.com/tensorflow/serving/blob/e085cb37b4b5c62154aa063dcbb781b24d5b3fd4/tensorflow_serving/example/mnist_client.py#L151)

```py
  for _ in range(num_tests): # <==

    request = predict_pb2.PredictRequest()
    request.model_spec.name = 'mnist'
    request.model_spec.signature_name = 'predict_images'
    image, label = test_data_set.next_batch(1)
    request.inputs['images'].CopyFrom(
        tf.make_tensor_proto(image[0], shape=[1, image[0].size]))

    result_counter.throttle() # <==

    result_future = stub.Predict.future(request, 5.0)  # 5 seconds
    result_future.add_done_callback(
        _create_rpc_callback(label[0], result_counter))
```

Based on my understanding, the above code is executed sequentially in the for loop.
I have read posts about condition variable, lock in Python. Since I don't even see multiple threads defined to send request, I don't think the code is related to concurrency even if I set the flag to e.g., 10. ([Define concurrency](https://github.com/tensorflow/serving/blob/master/tensorflow_serving/example/mnist_client.py#L45))

I may overlook gRPC if I have some misunderstanding.

If the code is not real concurrency, how to make it right?

Answer (score 1):

gRPC Python uses a background thread to polling messages from lower level. In order to run RPC concurrently, you can create multiple RPC futures in your thread. When any RPC is finished (result gathered by the background thread), then your callback will be invoked.

https://github.com/grpc/grpc/blob/0b4a9d6ba0a60a1982d81da6bb6b730a5c443c44/src/python/grpcio/grpc/_channel.py#L1126

Hope this helps, feel free to ask for more details.

Comment: Thank you for your comment.